# Looping a php multidimensional array and extract specific data

Tags: php

I have an multidimensional array from which i need to get some data, make some simple math and display them on a js graphic chart.
My only problem is that i can't get the data from the arrays.
This is how to array looks:

```
object(stdClass) [211]
        public 'countries' =>
            array (size=30)
                0 =>
                  array (size=1)
                    0 =>
                      object(stdClass)[215]
                         public 'country' => string 'RO' (lenght=2)
                         public 'clicks'  => int 4

                    1 =>
                      object(stdClass)[215]
                         public 'country' => string 'RU' (lenght=2)
                         public 'clicks'  => int 1

                1 =>
                   array (size=1)
                     0 =>
                       object(stdClass)[215]
                          public 'country' => string 'RU' (lenght=2)
                          public 'clicks'  => int 4

                     1 =>
                       object(stdClass)[215]
                          public 'country' => string 'RO' (lenght=2)
                          public 'clicks'  => int 2
```

...and so on till 29 (there are 30 days) so each day has clicks from different countries.
What i need to do is to extract the data from the array in this format:

```
name: ['RO', 'RU']
data: [6, 5]
```

I hope you understand what i am trying to do.
I am no expert, just a beginner and i can't work this out.

EDIT: in the end, i need to say that x country has x clicks on the last 30 days.
Be aware that i don't know witch countries are in the array because this is from an API that provides the top 10 countries by clicks.
So, in each day could be a country that wasn't in the day before and so on.

EDIT 2: this is what i have tried based on my experience:

```
function getCountriesByClicks($data)
{
    $jsData = [];
    $clicks = [];
    $country = [];
    for ($x = 0; $x < sizeof($data->data[0]->data->countries); $x++) {
        foreach ($data->data[0]->data->countries[$x] as $value) {
            array_push($country, $value->country);
            array_push($clicks, $value->clicks);
        }

        $jsData[] = ['name' => $country, 'data' => $clicks];
    }
    return json_encode($jsData);
}
```

Ignore the json return for it's just to use in my javascript graphic chart.

Thank you!

Comment: use foreach and collect the data...

Comment: I know that but it's not the answer that i am looking for.
Give me an example please!

Comment: I am not giving you the answer..

Comment: Then why did you bother to post a comment after all?!

Comment: Am i bothering your post?? Is it really true? So i am sorry...

Comment: Please, post only if you know what i want and only if you want to help me...

Comment: I think your foreach need some different pattern.

Comment: Looks like your `countries` dimension has the same key `0` multiple..

Comment: Really? Do you think so? :)

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
$name = array();
$data = array();
array_map(function($array){
    array_map(function($obj){
      $name[] = $obj->country;
      $data[] = $obj->clicks;
    },$array);
},$yourObject->countries);
```